# jq: Append JSON object via shell variable

Tags: macos, shell, zsh, jq

I have a JSON file and I'm trying to add another field to it.

*Example JSON File*:

```
{"data":{}}
```

Looking at other answers the `+=` seems to work:

```
objectName="objName"
cat $jsonFile | jq --arg objName $objectName '.data[$objName] += {"test": "json"}'
```

Outputs

```
{
  "data": {
    "objName": {
      "test": "json"
    }
  }
}
```

just as expected.

The problem is that I can't hardcode the JSON so I'm inputting the string as a variable. But I can't get the syntax to work:

```
objectName="objName"
objJSON='{"test": "json"}'
cat $jsonFile | jq -r --arg objName $objectName --arg jsonString $objJSON '.data[$objName] += $jsonString'
```

I'm getting the error `jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER, expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1: "json"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `--argjson` rather than `--arg` when passing JSON rather than strings.
2. When in doubt, quote your strings; that way if the shell executing your code isn't the one you think it is, you won't have your values being munged. (It's also helpful to stay in the habits necessary to write portable code; the whole reason I dropped zsh after spending 6 months learning it back in the mid-2000s is that my code quality when writing for other shells suffered).

---

```
objName="objName"
objJSON='{"test": "json"}'
echo '{"data":{}}' |
  jq --arg     objectName "$objName" \
     --argjson jsonString "$objJSON" \
    '.data[$objectName] += $jsonString'
```

...properly emits:

```
{
  "data": {
    "objName": {
      "test": "json"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm with this I get 
```jq: invalid JSON text passed to --argjson
Use jq --help for help with command-line options```

Comment: `objJSON='{"test": "json"}'`

Comment: hold on I think my Json is capitalized differently than yours

Comment: Run `set -x` to tell your shell to enable tracing so you can see the arguments it's actually passing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229307/discussion-between-evanlws-and-charles-duffy).

Comment: It looks like your script works. It was the capitalization difference between my `objJSON` and your `objJson` when I got the invalid JSON error

Comment: Between mine and yours it looks like I was missing -r

Comment: `-r` is actually a mistake on my part; it doesn't belong there (should only be used when output is raw strings, not JSON)

Comment: Ok so maybe it was the `--argjson issue`. I think I tried it a few attempts back but I must've messed up the quotes. Thanks!